# Is there any example code in C or Linux C to send PATCH command using curl library?

Tags: c, curl

I need to request for PATCH command with some header and data using curl command. But I am not getting how to send and how to frame PATCH command. Is there any example code,Pls share it.

Comment: Please add more details into the question. Otherwise this is nothing but "google for me please!?!"

Comment: There is a POST method in curl library like;CURLOPT_POST, I want to use some PATCH command. So how to use it in C?

Comment: Read https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST.html